# Exporting a list

Tags: r

I'm trying to export a list of 0's and 1's in R using the following code:

```
write(export, file="export.txt", ncol=1)
```

However, in the file "export.txt," there are 1's and 2's instead of 0's and 1's. How do I get the exported file to have 0's and 1's?

R List: `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1`

This is what shows up in the file: `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2`

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(export)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that `export` is a factor variable.  `write` is a wrapper for `cat` and `cat` doesn't seem to gracefully handle factors:

```
x <- factor(0:1)
cat(x)
## 1 2
```

You can coerce to character to get the proper output:

```
cat(as.character(x), file="export.txt")
## 0 1
```